# Symfony security.authentication_utils doesn't login

Tags: symfony, security, authentication

i'm trying to develop my first logiin page in symfony but my login form reload without any information (and redirect to the "authenticated" page )

Here's my code

security.yaml

```
security:
    providers:
      my_provider:
        entity:
            class: Company\Entity\User
            property: username

encoders:
    Company\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

firewalls:
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: my_provider
        pattern: ^/authenticated
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login

    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false    

access_control:
        - { path: ^/authenticated, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Here it is my controller

```
<?php
class AdminController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    dump($authenticationUtils);
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
    dump($lastUsername);
    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
}
```

And then my twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  {% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
  {% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post" >
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

If i use the http_basic authentication it works (with the entity provider). I've just introduced the login form and when i submit it reload the login page and keep me not authenticated.

[first dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHTC2.png)

Thank You

Comment: Hi. Password is crypted using bcrypt (cost: 13 - default) You can see in security.yaml section encoders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've solved the problem by deleting the pattern from *main* firewall even if i didn't understand yet why it doesn't work with the restriction configuration.